# MySQL SELECT statement where request parameter have more character than content in database

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, select

Let say i have a table of `city` like below

```
+-----+-------------------------+------+
| id  | city_name               | item |
+-----+-------------------------+------+
| 1   | kota jakarta            |  5   |
| 2   | tangerang               |  6   |
| 3   | kota tangerang selatan  |  7   |
| 4   | kota tangerang          |  8   |
```

in this case, i will get string input for `SELECT` statement, for example :

input = "**kota jakarta barat**" or "**kota jakarta selatan**" and i cant control the input, it come from web request.

my question :

(1) how to make `SELECT` query statement using above input to get exactly record result = "**kota jakarta**" ?

i cant use `SELECT city_name FROM city WHERE city_name like %kota jakarta barat%` because it will return nothing.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So your input is a list of word and you want to return what, every element have at least one match, some match, #% of match ? Because the second question seems to say otherwhise since it should not return `"kota tangerang selatan"`. (1) want to return "close match" but (2) need exact match. Please define what you need exactly.

Comment: yes, i think it's 2 different questions. should i open to another question  ?

Comment: @AxelH i have remove 2nd question.

Comment: i cant control the input, it come from web request. whats that mean please elaborate

Comment: @nikhilsugandh it mean, the input can be "kota jakarta pusat" or "kota jakarta timur" or many other....it's web request like this `http://localhost/api/city?="kota xyz abc"`

Comment: In order to understand more, would `REGEXP` be useful for your condition? Like `SELECT city_name  FROM city WHERE city_name REGEXP 'jakarta';`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 it would give the results, but the incoming parameter is `'kota jakarta barat` not `jakarta`, so if i run with regexp `kota jakarta barat` it would not give any results

Comment: So, if the data have `kota jakarta`, `kota jakarta timur`,`kota jakarta selatan` and not `kota jakarta barat`, the incoming parameter of `kota jakarta barat` will return `kota jakarta`, correct? If the incoming parameter is `kota jakarta timur`, and since the data is inside the table, it will return only `kota jakarta timur`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 the data inside table will only have `kota jakarta` where the input/incoming parameter can be `kota jakarta timur` , `kota jakarta barat` etc

Comment: If like that, referring to your example data, you have `kota tangerang and kota tangerang selatan`. In this case, if the input is non-existent in the data, for example `kota tangerang utara`, which one will it take?

Comment: @tcadidot0 for `kota tangerang utara` will return `kota tangerang`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT city_name AS result 
FROM city 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'kota tangerang selatan' AS input) i 
ON city.city_name=IF(city.city_name=i.input,i.input,SUBSTRING_INDEX(input,' ',2))
GROUP BY input;
```

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

```
FULLTEXT(city)

SELECT ...
    WHERE    MATCH(city) AGAINST("...")
    ORDER BY MATCH(city) AGAINST("...") DESC
```

That can get some unwanted results, such as "foo jakarta selatan"

Plan B:

This will be slow, but accurately looks for a prefix in the table:

```
WHERE LEFT("...", LENGTH(city)) = city
```

But that assumes that the desired city is a *prefix* of the requested string.

You might tack this on to get the 'best' match:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(city) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT city_name FROM Table1 
WHERE SOUNDEX(substring(city_name,1,12))= SOUNDEX(substring('kota 
jakarta',1,12));
```

or

```
SELECT city_name FROM city WHERE  SOUNDEX(substring(city_name,1,12))= 
SOUNDEX(substring(your input,1,12);
```

check:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc93c33/4

Comment: however, how about if we have no idea what exactly length of content in database. for this case : `SOUNDEX(substring(kota,1,12))` how about if i dont know length = 12 ?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is : 'When I write 'kota jakarta barat', I want to see records that contain both 'kota' and 'jakarta' and 'barat'', I think this can you give idea:

```
    INPUT = SUBSTRING("kota jakarta barat",1, POSITION(" " IN "kota jakarta barat")-1); --kota
INPUTLENGHT = LENGHT("kota jakarta barat"); --18 
POSITION("" IN (SUBSTRING("kota jakarta barat",POSITION(" " IN "kota jakarta barat")+1,INPUTLENGHT))); --8
INPUT2 = SUBSTRING("kota jakarta barat",POSITION(" " IN "kota jakarta barat"),POSITION("" IN (SUBSTRING("kota jakarta barat",POSITION(" " IN "kota jakarta barat")+1,INPUTLENGHT)))); --jakarta


SELECT city_name FROM city WHERE (city_name LIKE %INPUT% OR city_name LIKE %INPUT2% OR city_name LIKE %INPUT3%) ;
```

Comment: the error is `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INPUT = SUBSTRING("kota jakarta barat",1, POSITION(" " IN "kota jakarta barat")-' at line 1`

Comment: I wrote them(--kota, -- 18 etc.) for you to see the result. Can you delete them and try again?

Comment: if you run directly, you should define variables (INPUT, INPUTLENGHT)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably modify the pattern to be a regular expression.  The following will get a partial match:

```
where city_name regexp replace('kota jakarta selatan', ' ', '|')
```

EDIT:

You could also try:

```
where 'kota jakarta selatan' like concat(city_name, '%')
```

This works for your particular example.

Comment: Hi, is this query same as `SELECT * FROM city where city_name regexp ('kota|jakarta|selatan')` ?

Comment: but it give result : records that contain `kota` and `jakarta` and `selatan`. What i'm expecting is only `kota jakarta` (1 row only) . is this possible in SQL query ?

Comment: Hi, now it shows "kota jakarta" as result. but for some query, for example `SELECT * FROM city where 'kota tangerang selatan' like concat(city_name, '%')` will give records `"kota tangerang"` and `"kota tangerang selatan"`, i'm expecting only `"kota tangerang selatan"` see my edited question.